# How to use class name after getting class name from event.target in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code on HTML :

```js
$(".readMorebtn_id").on('click', function(e) {
  var icon = e.target;

  var parentDiv = $(icon).parent();
  var child = $(parentDiv).children(".afterReadMore_Class");
  var cls = $(child).attr('class');
  console.log(cls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="readMorediv_id">
  <button class="readMorebtn_id">Read More</button>
  <div class="afterReadMore_Class" style="display: none !important;">
    <div>
      <span><b>User CNIC:</b></span><span><?php  $row['usercnic']?></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><b>Father CNIC:</b></span><span><?php echo$row['fathercnic']?> 
         </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In jQuery, where I'm doing "`console.log(cls)`" class name is displaying in the console box. but I want to use this class name for the further process.

Comment: _but i want to use this class name for further process._ then just use it who stops you? what you mean exactly by _further process_?

Comment: So the question is _How to use global variables ?_

Comment: Please only add tags that are _directly_ related to the issue. The PHP tag here is irrelevant.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to describe?  `console.log(cls)` *is* "further processing".  You *are* using the `cls` variable *right there*.  So what isn't working?

Comment: actually i want to show this div that have "afterReadMore_Class"

Comment: what about $(".afterReadMore_Class").show() then?

Comment: john everything is working properly in above. i want to display div that have "afterReadMore_Class" in html code but it does not show when i call $(cls).show() in jquery

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y question. Why do you need to use the class of the element elsewhere when you already have a direct reference to the element itself?

Comment: You need `$("."+cls).show();` instead

Comment: yeah, you probably want to remove the "!important" in your inline-style of your element then ;)

Comment: haha jeff in this way all divs that have afterReadMore_Class shows up on the page.

Comment: theres only 1 div in your example. you need to explain your problem more clearly the next time please ;)
then just use .find(".afterReadMore_Class").show(), then. not that hard

Comment: Zakaria Acharki in this way all divs that have "afterReadMore_Class." shows up on page. and i want to only display that is the child of 'readMorediv_id' this div

Comment: jeff all divs will display when page is load. i mean i'm using loop so other divs will be create when page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like :

```
$(".readMorebtn_id").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".afterReadMore_Class").show();
});
```

That will show the related "afterReadMore_Class" of the clicked "readMorebtn_id".

```js
$(".readMorebtn_id").on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".afterReadMore_Class").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="readMorediv_id">
  <button class="readMorebtn_id">Read More</button>
  <div class="afterReadMore_Class" style="display: none !important;">
    <div>
      <span><b>User CNIC:</b></span><span><?php  $row['usercnic']?></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><b>Father CNIC:</b></span><span><?php echo$row['fathercnic']?> 
 </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="readMorediv_id">
  <button class="readMorebtn_id">Read More</button>
  <div class="afterReadMore_Class" style="display: none !important;">
    <div>
      <span><b>User CNIC:</b></span><span><?php  $row['usercnic']?></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><b>Father CNIC:</b></span><span><?php echo$row['fathercnic']?> 
 </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="readMorediv_id">
  <button class="readMorebtn_id">Read More</button>
  <div class="afterReadMore_Class" style="display: none !important;">
    <div>
      <span><b>User CNIC:</b></span><span><?php  $row['usercnic']?></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><b>Father CNIC:</b></span><span><?php echo$row['fathercnic']?> 
 </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly what i meant in the comments :)

Comment: Glad I could help brother.